# Accessing a CKAN resource in a local ckan installation

Tags: ckan

I have installed CKAN v2.5.2. I am running a local installation via paster. I have configured FileStore and am able to upload a file via the web interface. But, when I try to access the file by clicking the "go to resource" button I get a 'Not Found' error.

The URL is of the form:

> http://localhost/....

But, my ckan instance is running under paster and the link is missing the
port that paster is running on. So, the correct URL should be:

> http://localhost:5000/...

I have looked in the database and indeed it's incorrect there. Can someone let me know where CKAN is picking up the root url from? I am puzzled as to why the port is missing.

Many thanks,
adil

Answer (score 1):

Ok after a bit of searching around I found that the problem was I needed to ensure the ckan.site_url root in the development.ini file was set to the URL for my paster instance (eg http://localhost:5000/ckan). In case anyone else hits the same problem.